# C++ python module linking on MacOS

Tags: python, c++, macos, dylib, rpath

I'm building a C++ python module on MacOS.

On my machine I have python, installed in directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9`. I'm specifing python includes directory as `-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers` and libraries directory as `-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib -lpython3.9`.

So it builds good and runs good on my machine and other machines, where python is installed into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9`.

But when I move my library to machine, where python is installed into another folder, like `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9`, I'm getting import module error.

`otool -L _mymodule.so` command returns hardcoded absolute path to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9`. I know, that I can change the path using install_name_tool, but I don't want to ask and explain my module users to do that, as well as to make a symlink.

How can I make module more portable and python install path independent?

Comment: The only suitable for me way I've found is to add some common paths during building the library using install_name_tool:

install_name_tool -add_rpath /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.2/x64/lib ./bin/release/darwin/x64/_mylib.so

install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/python@3.10.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/${{ matrix.py }}/lib ./bin/release/darwin/x64/_mylib.so

install_name_tool -add_rpath /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10.2/lib ./bin/release/darwin/x64/_mylib.so